# How to explain this to my sir

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

We all know that $f = ma$.

But for finding displacement, we always use:

$$ s = s_0 + ut + \tfrac{1}{2} a t^2 $$

My sir, i don't know why for some reason uses this weird method:

$$ F = \frac{ms}{t^2} $$

I know the units don't match and i am sure this is wrong. Please confirm this for me and tell me what is wrong in his method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $s_0$ and $u$ are zero, then the equaion for $s$ simplifies to:

$$ s = \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 $$

so:

$$ \frac{ms}{t^2} = \tfrac{1}{2}ma $$

and since $F=ma$ this becomes:

$$ \frac{ms}{t^2} = \tfrac{1}{2}F $$

So, apart from the factor of $\tfrac{1}{2}$, the equation your teacher is using works for an object accelerating from rest. That factor of a half is a concern though ...

Comment: I get it. Thankyou very much...John